# Implemntation of AWS lambda function to resize images in S3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I am working on a project which uses the zoom functionality for images. In few images, zoom is not working. I need to know few things:
1) How AWS Lambda function helps me in this?? As the images are stored in the s3 bucket.
2) How to implement Lambda function on my local.

Comment: Pretty broad request here. What have you tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I've created lambda function which successfully resizes the image. I wanted to know, how it would be helpful in my zoom functionality.